# Established Security Design Patterns?

Tags: appsec, audit, sdl

In software engineering, a design pattern is a general reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context in software design. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Classification_and_list) lists many different design patterns for example, but security is never mentioned.

[Open SAMM](http://www.opensamm.org/) includes the following question in the audit checklist for Secure Architecture:
*Are project teams provided with prescriptive design patterns based on their application architecture?*

I never came across any established security design patterns that are considered state of the art from the community. Am I missing something here or are there no such security design patterns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing about security is that it's never a one-size-fits-all sort of deal. Because of that you always have to adapt designs to apply to the threats you're willing to counter. A good security design pattern is just a good software design pattern.

If you take a look at Wikipedia it lists a few: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Patterns

There is also an interesting website I came across while Googling: http://www.securitypatterns.org/patterns.html

Or if you take a look at CERT ( http://www.cert.org/archive/pdf/09tr010.pdf ) it lists a few. Here are some just from it's list of figures:

- Defer to Kernel Pattern
- Secure Factory Pattern Structure
- Secure Strategy Factory Pattern Structure
- Secure Builder Factory Pattern Structure
- Secure Chain of Responsibility Pattern Example
- Secure Chain of Responsibility Pattern Structure
- Secure State Machine Pattern Structure
- Secure State Machine Example Code Collaboration Diagram
- Secure Visitor Pattern Structure
- Secure Visitor Example Code Collaboration Diagram
- Secure Logger Pattern Structure
- Clear Sensitive Information Pattern Structure
- Structure of the Input Validation Pattern

Comment: These patterns are mostly relevant for applets and other situations when your code executes in untrusted environment. They are generally useless for, say, web apps.

Answer (score 0):

While we wait for [this book](http://isbn.nu/0321718399), you can read and postulate the writings of Rohit Sethi in [PDF] Securing the Core JEE Patterns[2](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Security_Analysis_of_Core_J2EE_Design_Patterns_Project) [PDF].

Also be sure to check out the project he runs on a [Security Analysis of Core J2EE Design Patterns](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Security_Analysis_of_Core_J2EE_Design_Patterns_Project).